# Workflow with Sass + Git

Tags: git, sass, workflow

I am relative new to sass and git, I found some good articles how to stop "cowboy-coding" now my workflow is the following:

1. Create repository
2. Clone repo local on xampp
3. Clone repo on the webserver and install a webhook
4. Copy a template in it ([link](https://bitbucket.org/elektronikprinting/git-template/src))
5. installing gulp + sass + sourcemaps
6. work!
7. commit + push to origin

I repeat step 5 + 6 as long as the project is finished! There appears my first problem. sometimes when I push the two versions are not 100% identical. Does I have to do something else then just push from local to git and pull from git to webserver??

Another Problem is, when the designer comes and tell me something looks awful how can I change something in sass? should I change it local and then push it and the server pulls it? or how else?

Comment: The two versions of what are not identical when you push?

Generally I'd create the repo on Github, pull down locally, then push the master branch up to the server. When working, I'd make changes locally in a new branch, commit them, then push to GH. I merge into master on GH, pull master down to local, then push up to the server.

That way GH is where the history is tracked and the server only has "finished" code. Same process for design fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change your all file locally, push to Your Repository and server will pull